# Problem with mixture of distributions solution

Tags: probability, expectation, moment-generating-functions

I have a problem with two competing solutions giving different answers.  I know the right one, but I want to understand why the other solution does not work.

> (Paraphrase from an ACTEX SOA Exam P Handbook problem)
>
> Random variables $J$, $K$, and $L$ have moment generating functions $M_J(t)=(1-2t)^{-3}$, $M_K(t)=(1-2t)^{-2.5}$, and $M_L(t)=(1-2t)^{-4.5}$.  Set $X=J+K+L$.  Compute $\mathbb{E}[X^3]$.

My first approach was as follows.  **The question is what the error in this solution attempt is**.

According to the ACTEX study guide, moment generating functions are linear for weighted averages (that is, if $S=\displaystyle\sum a_i S_i$, where $\displaystyle\sum a_i=1$, $a_i\geq0$, then the moment generating function is the corresponding linear combination of the moment generating functions of the component random variables $M_S(t)=\displaystyle\sum a_iM_{S_i}(t)$).

Since $X/3=\frac{1}{3}J+\frac{1}{3}K+\frac{1}{3}L$ is a weighted average, I applied the above fact to $X/3$.  Thus $$M_{X/3}(t)=\frac{1}{3}((1-2t)^{-3}+(1-2t)^{-2.5}+(1-2t)^{-4.5}).$$  I then computed $\frac{1}{27}\mathbb{E}[X^3]=\mathbb{E}[(X/3)^3]={M_{X/3}}'''(0)=694$, which then gives $\mathbb{E}[X]=18738$.  This is the wrong answer, and **I want to understand the error in my above reasoning**.

To save answerers the trouble, I will give the correct (and easier!) approach.  In fact the moment generating function turns sums of independent random variables into products as follows: if $S=\displaystyle\sum c_jS_j$ (not a weighted average), then $M_S(t)=\displaystyle\prod M_{S_i}(c_it)$.  Thus $$M_X(t)=(1-2t)^{-3}\cdot(1-2t)^{-2.5}\cdot(1-2t)^{-4.5}=(1-2t)^{-10}.$$

From this we can compute the correct answer of $\mathbb{E}[X^3]={M_X}'''(0)=10560$.
Thanks!

Comment: Pls. read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function#Linear_combination_of_independent_random_variables

Comment: @zoli All this link does is explain where the correct solution comes from, which I already have in the statement of the question.  The point of the question is to try to understand the mistake in my wrong solution.

Comment: Rather than using the product, you used a sum.

Comment: Make sure you can distinguish between a mixture and a linear combination.

Comment: @BGM, you are right, that is the mistake I was using.  I thought that the density function of a linear combination was the linear combination of the density functions, but I now see that the latter idea is the mixture (according to the book, I think), and is not the same thing.  Thanks